# Regarding a observation in a class

Tags: java

I was observing today that by writing the below line in a simple java class

```
System.out.println(010|4);
```

gives the output of '12' , whats the logic behind that, please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|` is the [bitwise inclusive OR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) operator, `010` is octal for `8`, which is `1000` in binary, `4` is `100` in binary, so when you or each bit in `1000` with the corresponding bit in `0100` you get `1100` in binary which is `12`.

Answer (score 2):

When you prefix the number with 0, it's considered as base 8
meaning 010 = 0*(8^0) + 1*(8^1) = 8

| is bitwise OR operation

010|4 is same as 8|4

```
1000
OR
0100
=
1100
= 12
```

Answer (score 1):

`|` is the [bitwise inclusive OR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) operator and `010` is 8 in octal, so 8 | 4 = 12.

Answer (score 1):

```
010|4
```

Here two thing notable-

1. 010 - Integer starts with 0 . It is a octal number. `ex 011 -> 9 (0 8^1 8^0 =9)`
2. | - bitwise or a | b it tells 1 if either bit is 1. `ex 010 | 010 -> 8 (010)`

In this case

```
 010 | 4 -> 010 | 04 -> 014 
 014 which is 12 in base of 10
```